# Should jest/enzyme be a devDependency or dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

Should testing libraries being used in frontend like `jest`, `enzyme` or `react-testing-library` be part of `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in your `package.json`?

Since testing is not part of your build compilation I think it should be in `devDependencies` but your testing suites run mostly in your pipelines while being deployed on server i.e, Jenkins, TravisCI etc. Which makes me wonder since it's being used in production shouldn't these be listed in `dependencies` section.

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: `dev` since it's not required for runtime of your app

Comment: But it is needed in production in dev pipeline. Can you please reference your argument with a link or something?

Comment: Sure, [doc link](https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file). Rule of thumb is if end user doesn't need this library or dependency - it shouldn't be in dependencies.

Comment: Unless your pipeline is installing dependencies with the production flag, it should also install the dev dependencies.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

devDependencies are modules which are only required during development, while dependencies are required during runtime. **Jest/Enzyme are only required during development** , therefore should be saved as devDependencies.